# Raspberry Pi 2 and thermal printer

Tags: python, pi-2, printing

I try to print some text with python and a thermal receipt printer by a Raspberry Pi 2 model B.
I use the library developped by Adafruit and the printer sold by Adafruit too.
But it fails. The only thing working is the println function, and at least not well.
I have to print some characters like ``` .--``[#]..--``--. ``` but I have some random results.
Sometimes the line is correctly printed, sometimes the line is vertically mid printed (like a negative interline), sometimes not all the characters.

I use an AC power adaptor from an old Sony electronic equipment to power the printer. Output: DC5V 800mA. The printer is connected to the PI by GPIO and powered by the Sony power supply.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Adafruit_Thermal import *
printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/ttyAMA0", 19200, timeout=5)
printer.setSize('S')
def printfile():
   with open('output') as f:a=f.read()
   a=a.splitlines()
   for i in range(int(len(a))):
      printer.println(a[i])
printfile()
```

an output file example:

```
                 [#]            
                [#]]            
                [#]             
            .--``||.            
        .--`     |  .--``--.    
        |       .--`        `--.
        `--.    |              |
`--.        .--``--.           |
 x x`--..--[#]      `--.    .--`
    .--``-[#]][#]      |.--`    
.--`      [#]-[#]   .--`        
|     {`}  ||--|`--.            
`--.    .--|   |x   `--.        
    `--.|              |        
        `--.        .--`        
            `--..--`
```

I saw that when it is bad printed, a red led blinks under the printer, that means there are some errors...

Any Idea ?

Links:

- Thermal receipt printer: https://www.adafruit.com/products/597
- Python library: https://github.com/adafruit/Python-Thermal-Printer

Comment: Have you checked that your power supply is not overloaded?

Comment: How is the printer powered and connected to the Pi? You should also link to the product and tutorial on adafruit's site in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your power supply is inadequate for the printer.  According to Adafruit's documentation (on the link you provided), the printer requires a power supply that can support at least 1.5A output.